# How to deal with extra characters read into ASIO streambuf?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Most libraries has parsers works only over `std::istream` or single continuous buffer. Those parsers read istream until the eof, not the end of document.  Even if there is a nice `boost::asio::streambuf`, that can be used with `istream`, there is a problem with reading and committing only one frame to it. Functions like `read_until` are committing anything that they read, and if they read a fragment of next frame, the parsing fill fail.

This mocked **<kbd>[example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f33dd265c016d8)</kbd>** is showing the problem.

Assuming that we need an efficient solution, without copying buffers, I need to ensure that the end of stream is the correct end of document. My current solution is to scan data and do multiply commit/consume over one prepared buffer:

```
size_t read_some_frames( boost::asio::streambuf& strbuf, 
                         std::function< void(istream&) > parser ) {
        auto buffers= strbuf.prepare( 1024 );
        size_t read= bad_case_of_read_some( buffers );

        vector< std::pair< size_t, size_t > > frames;
        std::pair< size_t, size_t > leftover= scanForFrames( 
                    buffers_begin(buffers), 
                    buffers_begin(buffers)+read, 
                    frames, '\0' );

        for( auto const& frame: frames ) {
            cout << "Frame size: " << frame.first 
                      << " skip: " << frame.second << endl;
            strbuf.commit( frame.first );
            strbuf.consume( frame.second );
            iostream stream( &strbuf );
            parser( stream );
        }
        cout << "Unfinished frame size: " << leftover.first 
                             << " skip:" << leftover.second << endl;
        strbuf.commit( leftover.first );
        strbuf.consume( leftover.second );
        return read;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bb25a6dad3fc044)</kbd>**

According to [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/commit.html), this is wrong. I think this code work, because that calling [commit and consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552785/boost-asio-streambuf-dont-release-memory-after-calling-consume) do not release the internal buffers. Somehow I need to deal with this.

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Can you clarify "rewriting (freezing current)"? And "rewriting (freezing current)". I think you were trying to be very accurate, but you ended up being so terse that these bits can pretty much mean anything to me :/

Comment: Also. Is it correct to assume that `\0` is the frame delimiter here? (In that case I also think the mock data is flawed, because the string literals include implicit trailing NUL chars)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the [`read_until()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html) operations commit all data read into the streambuf's input sequence, they return a `bytes_transferred` value containing the number of bytes up to and including the first delimiter.  In essence, it provides the size of the frame, and one can limit `istream` to only read a portion of the `streambuf`'s input sequence by either:

- Using a custom `istream` that limits the amount of bytes read from a streambuf.  One of the easier ways to accomplish this is to use Boost.IOStream's [`boost::iostreams::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream) and implement a model of the [Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html) concept.
- Create a custom `streambuf` that derives from Boost.Asio's `streambuf`.  To limit the amount of bytes read from the available input sequence, custom functions will need to manipulate the end of the input sequence.  Furthermore, the custom `streambuf` will need to handle underflow.

---

#### Custom `Source` for Boost.IOStream

Boost.IOStream's `boost::iostreams::stream` object delegates I/O operations to a Device.  The Device is user code that implements a model of various Boost.IOStream concepts.  In this case, the Source concept, which provides read-access to a sequence of characters, is the only one needed.  Furthermore, when the `boost::iostreams::stream` uses a Source Device, it will inherit from `std::basic_istream`.

In the following code, `asio_streambuf_input_device` is a model of the Source concept that reads from a Boost.Asio streambuf.  When a given amount of bytes have been read, `asio_streambuf_input_device` indicates underflow even if the underlying streambuf still has data in its input sequence.

```cpp
/// Type that implements a model of the Boost.IOStream's Source concept
/// for reading data from a Boost.Asio streambuf
class asio_streambuf_input_device
  : public boost::iostreams::source // Use convenience class.
{
public:

  explicit
  asio_streambuf_input_device(
      boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf,
      std::streamsize bytes_transferred
  )
    : streambuf_(streambuf),
      bytes_remaining_(bytes_transferred)
  {}

  std::streamsize read(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize buffer_size)
  {
    // Determine max amount of bytes to copy.
    auto bytes_to_copy =
      std::min(bytes_remaining_, std::min(
          static_cast<std::streamsize>(streambuf_.size()), buffer_size));

    // If there is no more data to be read, indicate end-of-sequence per
    // Source concept.
    if (0 == bytes_to_copy)
    {
      return -1; // Indicate end-of-sequence, per Source concept.
    }

    // Copy from the streambuf into the provided buffer.
    std::copy_n(buffers_begin(streambuf_.data()), bytes_to_copy, buffer);

    // Update bytes remaining.
    bytes_remaining_ -= bytes_to_copy;

    // Consume from the streambuf.
    streambuf_.consume(bytes_to_copy);

    return bytes_to_copy;
  }

private:
  boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf_;
  std::streamsize bytes_remaining_;
};

// ...

// Create a custom iostream that sets a limit on the amount of bytes
// that will be read from the streambuf.
boost::iostreams::stream<asio_streambuf_input_device> input(streambuf, n);
parse(input);
```

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0a460c9248a524c) this approach:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp>  // boost::iostreams::source
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

/// Type that implements a model of the Boost.IOStream's Source concept
/// for reading data from a Boost.Asio streambuf
class asio_streambuf_input_device
  : public boost::iostreams::source // Use convenience class.
{
public:

  explicit
  asio_streambuf_input_device(
      boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf,
      std::streamsize bytes_transferred
  )
    : streambuf_(streambuf),
      bytes_remaining_(bytes_transferred)
  {}

  std::streamsize read(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize buffer_size)
  {
    // Determine max amount of bytes to copy.
    auto bytes_to_copy =
      std::min(bytes_remaining_, std::min(
          static_cast<std::streamsize>(streambuf_.size()), buffer_size));

    // If there is no more data to be read, indicate end-of-sequence per
    // Source concept.
    if (0 == bytes_to_copy)
    {
      return -1; // Indicate end-of-sequence, per Source concept.
    }

    // Copy from the streambuf into the provided buffer.
    std::copy_n(buffers_begin(streambuf_.data()), bytes_to_copy, buffer);

    // Update bytes remaining.
    bytes_remaining_ -= bytes_to_copy;

    // Consume from the streambuf.
    streambuf_.consume(bytes_to_copy);

    return bytes_to_copy;
  }

private:
  boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf_;
  std::streamsize bytes_remaining_;
};

/// @brief Convert a streambuf to a string.
std::string make_string(boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf)
{
  return std::string(buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
                     buffers_end(streambuf.data()));
}

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect client and server sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, std::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), std::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();

  // Write to client.
  const std::string message =
    "12@"
    "345@";
  write(server_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));

  boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

  {
    auto bytes_transferred = read_until(client_socket, streambuf, '@');
    // Verify that the entire message "12@345@" was read into
    // streambuf's input sequence.
    assert(message.size() == streambuf.size());
    std::cout << "streambuf contains: " << make_string(streambuf) <<
                  std::endl;

    // Create a custom iostream that sets a limit on the amount of bytes
    // that will be read from the streambuf.
    boost::iostreams::stream<asio_streambuf_input_device> input(
      streambuf, bytes_transferred);

    int data = 0;
    input >> data; // Consumes "12" from input sequence.
    assert(data == 12);
    std::cout << "Extracted: " << data << std::endl;
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // Consume "@" from input sequence.
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // No more data available.
    assert(input.eof());
    std::cout << "istream has reached EOF" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "streambuf contains: " << make_string(streambuf) <<
               std::endl;

  {
    // As the streambuf's input sequence already contains the delimiter,
    // this operation will not actually attempt to read data from the
    // socket.
    auto bytes_transferred = read_until(client_socket, streambuf, '@');

    // Create a custom iostream that sets a limit on the amount of bytes
    // that will be read from the streambuf.
    boost::iostreams::stream<asio_streambuf_input_device> input(
      streambuf, bytes_transferred);

    std::string data;
    getline(input, data, '@'); // Consumes delimiter.
    assert(data == "345");
    std::cout << "Extracted: " << data << std::endl;
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // Underflow.
    assert(input.eof());
    std::cout << "istream has reached EOF" << std::endl;
  }

  assert(streambuf.size() == 0);
  std::cout << "streambuf is empty" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
streambuf contains: 12@345@
Extracted: 12
istream has reached EOF
streambuf contains: 345@
Extracted: 345
istream has reached EOF
streambuf is empty
```

#### Derive from `boost::asio::streambuf`

One can safely derive from the Boost.Asio's `streambuf` and implement custom behaviors.  In this case, the goal is to limit the amount of bytes an `istream` can extract from the input sequence before causing underflow.  This can be accomplish by:

- Updating the streambuf's get-area (input sequence) pointers so it only contains the desired amount of bytes to be read.  This is accomplished by setting the end of the get-area pointer (`egptr`) to be `n` bytes after the current character get-area pointer (`gptr`).  In the code below, I refer to this as *framing*.
- Handling a `underflow()`.  If the end of the current *frame* has been reached, then return `EOF`.

```cpp
/// @brief Type that derives from Boost.Asio streambuf and can frame the
///        input sequence to a portion of the actual input sequence.
template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<char> >
class basic_framed_streambuf
  : public boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>
{
private:

  typedef boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator> parent_type;

public:

  explicit 
  basic_framed_streambuf(
    std::size_t maximum_size = (std::numeric_limits< std::size_t >::max)(),
    const Allocator& allocator = Allocator()
  )
    : parent_type(maximum_size, allocator),
      egptr_(nullptr)
  {}

  /// @brief Limit the current input sequence to n characters.
  ///
  /// @remark An active frame is invalidated by any member function that
  ///        modifies the input or output sequence.
  void frame(std::streamsize n)
  {
    // Store actual end of input sequence.
    egptr_ = this->egptr();
    // Set the input sequence end to n characters from the current
    // input sequence pointer..
    this->setg(this->eback(), this->gptr(), this->gptr() + n);
  }

  /// @brief Restore the end of the input sequence.
  void unframe()
  {
    // Restore the end of the input sequence.
    this->setg(this->eback(), this->gptr(), this->egptr_);
    egptr_ = nullptr;
  }

protected:

  // When the end of the input sequence has been reached, underflow
  // will be invoked.
  typename parent_type::int_type underflow()
  {
    // If the  streambuf is currently framed, then return eof
    // on underflow.  Otherwise, defer to the parent implementation.
    return egptr_ ? parent_type::traits_type::eof()
                  : parent_type::underflow();
  }

private:
  char* egptr_;
};

// ...

basic_framed_streambuf<> streambuf;
// ....
streambuf.frame(n);
std::istream input(&streambuf);
parse(input);
streambuf.unframe();
```

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8eb56953e61bbf1e) this approach:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

/// @brief Type that derives from Boost.Asio streambuf and can frame the
///        input sequence to a portion of the actual input sequence.
template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<char> >
class basic_framed_streambuf
  : public boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>
{
private:

  typedef boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator> parent_type;

public:

  explicit 
  basic_framed_streambuf(
    std::size_t maximum_size = (std::numeric_limits< std::size_t >::max)(),
    const Allocator& allocator = Allocator()
  )
    : parent_type(maximum_size, allocator),
      egptr_(nullptr)
  {}

  /// @brief Limit the current input sequence to n characters.
  ///
  /// @remark An active frame is invalidated by any member function that
  ///        modifies the input or output sequence.
  void frame(std::streamsize n)
  {
    // Store actual end of input sequence.
    egptr_ = this->egptr();
    // Set the input sequence end to n characters from the current
    // input sequence pointer..
    this->setg(this->eback(), this->gptr(), this->gptr() + n);
  }

  /// @brief Restore the end of the input sequence.
  void unframe()
  {
    // Restore the end of the input sequence.
    this->setg(this->eback(), this->gptr(), this->egptr_);
    egptr_ = nullptr;
  }

protected:

  // When the end of the input sequence has been reached, underflow
  // will be invoked.
  typename parent_type::int_type underflow()
  {
    // If the  streambuf is currently framed, then return eof
    // on underflow.  Otherwise, defer to the parent implementation.
    return egptr_ ? parent_type::traits_type::eof()
                  : parent_type::underflow();
  }

private:
  char* egptr_;
};

typedef basic_framed_streambuf<> framed_streambuf;

/// @brief RAII type that helps frame a basic_framed_streambuf within a 
///        given scope.
template <typename Streambuf>
class streambuf_frame
{
public:
  explicit streambuf_frame(Streambuf& streambuf, std::streamsize n)
    : streambuf_(streambuf)
  {
    streambuf_.frame(n);
  }

  ~streambuf_frame() { streambuf_.unframe(); }

  streambuf_frame(const streambuf_frame&) = delete;
  streambuf_frame& operator=(const streambuf_frame&) = delete;

private:
  Streambuf& streambuf_;
};

/// @brief Convert a streambuf to a string.
std::string make_string(boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf)
{
  return std::string(buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
                     buffers_end(streambuf.data()));
}

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect client and server sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, std::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), std::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();

  // Write to client.
  const std::string message =
    "12@"
    "345@";
  write(server_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));

  framed_streambuf streambuf;

  // Demonstrate framing the streambuf's input sequence manually.
  {
    auto bytes_transferred = read_until(client_socket, streambuf, '@');
    // Verify that the entire message "12@345@" was read into
    // streambuf's input sequence.
    assert(message.size() == streambuf.size());
    std::cout << "streambuf contains: " << make_string(streambuf) <<
                  std::endl;

    // Frame the streambuf based on bytes_transferred.  This is all data
    // up to and including the first delimiter.
    streambuf.frame(bytes_transferred);

    // Use an istream to read data from the currently framed streambuf.
    std::istream input(&streambuf);
    int data = 0;
    input >> data; // Consumes "12" from input sequence.
    assert(data == 12);
    std::cout << "Extracted: " << data << std::endl;
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // Consume "@" from input sequence.
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // No more data available in the frame, so underflow.
    assert(input.eof());
    std::cout << "istream has reached EOF" << std::endl;

    // Restore the streambuf.
    streambuf.unframe();
  }

  // Demonstrate using an RAII helper to frame the streambuf's input
  // sequence.
  {
    // As the streambuf's input sequence already contains the delimiter,
    // this operation will not actually attempt to read data from the
    // socket.
    auto bytes_transferred = read_until(client_socket, streambuf, '@');
    std::cout << "streambuf contains: " << make_string(streambuf) <<
                  std::endl;

    // Frame the streambuf based on bytes_transferred.  This is all data
    // up to and including the first delimiter.  Use a frame RAII object
    // to only frame the streambuf within the current scope.
    streambuf_frame<framed_streambuf> frame(streambuf, bytes_transferred);

    // Use an istream to read data from the currently framed streambuf.
    std::istream input(&streambuf);
    std::string data;
    getline(input, data, '@'); // Consumes delimiter.
    assert(data == "345");
    std::cout << "Extracted: " << data << std::endl;
    assert(!input.eof());
    input.get(); // No more data available in the frame, so underflow.
    assert(input.eof());
    std::cout << "istream has reached EOF" << std::endl;
    // The frame object's destructor will unframe the streambuf.
  }

  assert(streambuf.size() == 0);
  std::cout << "streambuf is empty" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
streambuf contains: 12@345@
Extracted: 12
istream has reached EOF
streambuf contains: 345@
Extracted: 345
istream has reached EOF
streambuf is empty
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside the case where you consume a stream after reading until the connection has been closed, I see no use for strbuf + istream like this, indeed.

The simple problem being that istream extraction will not update the stream atomically on failed/partial parsem leading to lost input/corruption.

Here's your mock sample fixed to [correctly *expect* **and** *receive* NUL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415142/how-to-deal-with-extra-characters-read-into-asio-streambuf#comment45166925_28415142):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0511585a7c3242e)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

std::istream &parseDocument(std::istream &is, int &data) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    return is >> qi::match(qi::int_ >> '\0', data);
}

template <typename MutableBuffers> size_t 
    fake_read1(MutableBuffers const &outbuf) { return asio::buffer_copy(outbuf, asio::buffer("12345" "\0" "23", 8)); }

template <typename MutableBuffers> size_t 
    fake_read2(MutableBuffers const &outbuf) { return asio::buffer_copy(outbuf, asio::buffer("456" "\0", 4)); }

#define READ_UNTIL(/*boost::asio::streambuf &*/strbuf, fake_read) { \
    auto buffers = strbuf.prepare(1024); \
    size_t read = fake_read(buffers); \
    std::cout << "READ_UNTIL " #fake_read ": " << read << " bytes\n"; \
    strbuf.commit(read); \
}

int main() {
    // this is the easy scenario:
    {
        asio::streambuf strbuf;

        READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read1);
        READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read2);

        int data1, data2;
        std::istream stream(&strbuf);

        parseDocument(stream, data1);
        parseDocument(stream, data2);

        std::cout << "Yo: " << data1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Yo: " << data2 << "\n";
    }

    // this is the tricky scenario:
    {
        asio::streambuf strbuf;

        READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read1);
        //READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read2); // will happen later, now we're stuck with a partial second frame

        int data1, data2;
        std::istream stream(&strbuf);

        parseDocument(stream, data1);

        while (!parseDocument(stream, data2)) {
            stream.clear();
            READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read2);
        }

        std::cout << "Oops: " << data1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Oops: " << data2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

In the "tricky" scenario you can see that the partial packet (containing "23") is lost and the subsequent packet corrupted:

```
READ_UNTIL fake_read1: 8 bytes
READ_UNTIL fake_read2: 4 bytes
Oops: 12345
Oops: 456
```

You can also see I switch to my preferred framework for small, ad-hoc, parsers: Boost Spirit in the `parseDocument()` function. See below for how I'd make this more applicable.

### 1. Underflowing Stream Buffers

What you *could* be looking for instead is a stream buffer implementation that would just await more data when the buffer underflows.

I believe that e.g. `asio::ip::tcp::iostream` is exactly that:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cd69c9a5d20fe38)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream("127.0.0.1", "6769").rdbuf();
}
```

> Run this locally to see that input arrives packet-wise (e.g. with netcat)

### 2. Parsing the underlying `ConstBuffers` sequence

Alternatively, and in the spirit of zero-copy you might want to parse directly on the underlying buffer sequence that underlies the `asio::streambuf` implementation, making sure to only `consume()` what you've ***successfully*** parsed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a22ae26f7c1c1c2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

using asio::buffers_begin;
using asio::buffers_end;

template <typename ConstBuffers>
size_t parseDocument(ConstBuffers const& buffers, int &data) {

    auto b(buffers_begin(buffers)), f=b, l(buffers_end(buffers));

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    return qi::phrase_parse(f, l, qi::int_ >> '\0', qi::space, data)
        ? (f - b) 
        : 0; // only optionally consume
}

template <typename MutableBuffers> size_t 
    fake_read1(MutableBuffers const &outbuf) { return asio::buffer_copy(outbuf, asio::buffer("12345" "\0" "23", 8)); }

template <typename MutableBuffers> size_t 
    fake_read2(MutableBuffers const &outbuf) { return asio::buffer_copy(outbuf, asio::buffer("456" "\0", 4)); }

#define READ_UNTIL(/*boost::asio::streambuf &*/strbuf, fake_read) { \
    auto buffers = strbuf.prepare(1024); \
    size_t read = fake_read(buffers); \
    std::cout << "READ_UNTIL " #fake_read ": " << read << " bytes\n"; \
    strbuf.commit(read); \
}

size_t readuntil2(boost::asio::streambuf &strbuf) {

    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    static int delay_fake_async_receive = 6;
    if (delay_fake_async_receive--)
        return 0;

    auto buffers = strbuf.prepare(1024);
    size_t read = fake_read2(buffers);
    std::cout << "read2: " << read << " bytes\n";
    strbuf.commit(read);
    return read;
}

#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main() {
    // this is the tricky scenario:
    asio::streambuf strbuf;

    READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read1);
    //READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read2); // will happen later, now we're stuck with a partial second frame

    int data1=0, data2=0;

    strbuf.consume(parseDocument(strbuf.data(), data1));

    size_t consumed = 0;
    while (!(consumed = parseDocument(strbuf.data(), data2))) {
        READ_UNTIL(strbuf, fake_read2);
    }

    std::cout << "Yay: " << data1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Yay: " << data2 << "\n";

    //asio::ip::tcp::iostream networkstream("localhost", "6767");
    std::cout << asio::ip::tcp::iostream("localhost", "6767").rdbuf();
}
```

Prints

```
READ_UNTIL fake_read1: 8 bytes
READ_UNTIL fake_read2: 4 bytes
Yay: 12345
Yay: 23456
```

### SUMMARY, Integrating 3rd party parsers

If you **must** use a third party library that *requires* a `std::istream&` to parse from, yet you cannot rely on transmissions to be aligned with frame boundaries, you could perhaps use a hybrid approach:

```
auto n = find_frame_boundary(buffers_begin(sb.data()), buffers_end(sb.data()));
```

and then perhaps use a `boost::iostream::array_source` on the reduced region detected.

Comment: No. Your answer is good, one possible solution is to rewrite a parser. I just thought that my questions says that I want to use external parsers, that runs over iostream.

Comment: You "just thought" your question says...? I "think" my answer addresses that (unless you bailed before the summary). And yes, I confirm your point out this limiting the use of `asio::streambuf` with keep-alive streams (e.g. long-polling etc.).

Comment: Yes, that was my approach, but instead of using `array_source` witch is not  documented in public api reference, I perform many calls on `asio::streambuf` to commit only to the end of document, parse the document, and then commit the next frame and consume the frame boundaries.

Comment: Oh thats other library ;-D

Comment: @Arpegius sadly I don't think you can do better, unless you make the streambuf a kind of "infinite stream" with proper underflow. More like a dynamic size ringbuffer.

Comment: Some great information and approaches here.  I do want to note that I think the original question's mocked up example was missing a critical piece of information. The Boost.Asio `read_until()` operations return the number of bytes in the streambuf's get area up to and including the delimiter.  With that information, one should be able to avoid trying to parse a partial frame.

Comment: @TannerSansbury That's sweet. I didn't know that. It might be slightly confusing, but at least it is a lot more useful then!